# Static route between 2 routers

Tags: networking, routing, ip-routing

Hello I have problem with static routing between 2 simple (Zyxel and TPLink) routers. vDSL Router 1 has 192.168.0.1/25 with enabled DHCP and Router 2 has 10.0.0.1/25 also with DHCP

Router 1 and Router 2 are connected with cat5e. From ethernet port 3 (Router1) to WAN port on Router 2.

I want to connect from PC1 to small server (nVidia Jetson). As far as know i should make static route on router 1.

My routing settings on Router1:

[image]

As far I know, the settings "should" be correct. But I can't ping from PC1 to any IP that are in 10.0.0.0/25 subnet.

Can anyone help me, or just point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Network map:

[image]

Static route settings

Comment: Your Router 2 most probably blocks all incoming packages on the WAN interface. You will need co configure it to allow incoming connections.

Comment: I am still stuck, u point me to the right direction, but i tried 2 different routers (netis, tp-link) and tried different settings. There is no good firewall option to be disabled, there is no firewall settings at all... Where should i set it? Port forwarding? Routing?

Comment: From PC1-4, can you ping 192.168.0.3 (I assume the WAN interface of R2)?

Comment: yes, ping from PC1-4 to R2 WAN works

Comment: and from R2 (and clients)  i can access to 192.168.0.1 and also to the internet.

Comment: Your router 2 is probably trying to do NAT on the WAN interface. You need to turn off NAT on router 2.